# External vs internal pull-up resistor

Tags: resistors, esp8266, pullup, nodemcu

I'm using an esp8266 to read signals from a water meter.  The meter periodically closes a switch between two wires.

My prototype circuit works fine with either an external pull-up resistor, or using the internal resistor in the microcontroller.  Is there any advantage to using one or the other?

Thanks!

details:

- Microcontroller: HiLetgo ESP8266 NodeMCU CP2102 ESP-12E
- Meter: DAE MJ-75

Comment: I think the combined answers at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/69637/external-vs-internal-pullup should answer this question.

Comment: @ocrdu thank you

Comment: No problem, I like Zwiebelspätzle.